# The same error i all headers - error: expected '='... before 'protocol'

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, header

I've been working on an iOS project for some time but now I have an error which really confuses me and as long as I can't fix it I can't even compile the project so I need some serious help!

It all began with an:

error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '**attribute**' before 'protocol'

in PHCluesListViewController.h. The class had not been changed for a long time and what I was working on at the moment of the error had nothing to do with that particular class.

This is what it looks like:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol PHCluesListViewControllerDelegate;

@class PHClueListTableViewController;

@interface PHCluesListViewController : UIViewController {

    IBOutlet PHClueListTableViewController *clueListTableViewController;

    id <PHCluesListViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
}

- (void)mapDelegate;

@property (nonatomic, assign) id <PHCluesListViewControllerDelegate> delegate;

@end

@protocol PHCluesListViewControllerDelegate

- (void)mapUp:(PHCluesListViewController *)controller;

@end
```

There are no syntax errors and there is nothing wrong with the code in it's context either. Later I would learn that if you were to take away all the code from the header file the error would move to a another random header file or if you were to import another header the error would move to this header.

I've tried to restart xcode, to move the project to a new one, to rewrite the code to a new file and to move the project to another computer with another version of xcode - but with no luck.

I am able to run other xcode-projects on my computer.

It seems to me that xcode are trying to compile my headers in this specific project in some unwanted fashion.

Help would be highly appreciated, thanks on before hand!

---------- EDIT!!! ----------

Thanks for the fast respond!! Although I've found the answer.

The error was a "d" written out of bounds of the implementation in a totally different file/class. Found it by chance...

If something similar would happen to anyone else; check for something like a letter written after @end or before @interface/@implementation or anything else that would "cut the edges" of the common syntax.

It's difficult to find the reason for an error like this and I'm a little bit surprised that I found it so quickly among 80 files (only 4.5 hours).

Good luck!!

Comment: If this is affecting every source file in your project/target, check the corresponding prefix header(s) (.pch).

Comment: Try compiling it using clang if you're not; its error messages are much more useful (in my experience).

Answer (score 0):

You're defining @protocol PHCluesListViewControllerDelegate twice. Also, if mapUp is required to be implemented, you might want to add the @required keyword.

Comment: He’s not defining the protocol twice — `@protocol PHCluesListViewControllerDelegate;` is a forward declaration. Also, `@required` is default so that method already is required.